# Find $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ given that $f(0)=1$ and for all $a>0$, the arc length from $0$ to $a$ equals the $x$-intercept of the tangent at $a$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I made up the following problem.

A curve $y=f(x)$ passes through $(0,1)$, and for all $a>0$, the arc length of $y=f(x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=a$ equals the $x$-intercept of the tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$.

That is, in the graph below, the red arc and the red line segment have the same length.

[image]

> What is the area under the curve, $A=\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ ?

**My attempt**

We have

$$\int_0^a \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx=a-\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $a$ gives

$$\sqrt{1+(f'(a))^2}=1-\frac{(f'(a))^2-f(a)f''(a)}{(f'(a))^2}$$

$$(y')^6+(y')^4-(yy'')^2=0$$

But I don't know how to solve this differential equation.

Then I approximated the curve with a sequence of triangles as shown below.

[image]

Each of the colored line segments has length $\epsilon$, which approaches $0$.

Let $h_n$ be the height, and let $\theta_n$ be the lower-right angle, of the $n$th triangle from the left. Let $\theta_0=\pi/2$.

$h_n=1-\epsilon\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin{\theta_k}$

$\theta_n = \arctan{\left(\dfrac{h_n}{n\epsilon -\epsilon\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos{\theta_k}}\right)}$

I made an Excel simulation using these two equations, and it suggests that $A=1/3$. (The length of the longest side of the triangles seems to approach $1/2$.)

I tried to rearrange the triangles in some clever way to get a total area of $1/3$, but I haven't found a way.

Comment: maybe you can try it by expressing it as inversed function, i.e. $dx/dy$

Comment: Differentiate the differential equation two times

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi That leaves me with a very long equation involving first, second, third and fourth derivatives. Then what?

Comment: That was a guess, I am not able to work out after that

Comment: The definition of this curve is similar to (but different from) one definition of the tractrix, another transcendental curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Regard $x$ as a function of $y$, so that the tangent line to the graph at $(x(b), b)$ is $T(y) = x'(b) (y - b) + x(b)$; then our condition is:
$$\int_b^1 \sqrt{1 + x'(y)^2} \,dy = T(0) = x(b) - b x'(b) .$$
Differentiating with respect to $b$, renaming $b$ as $y$, and rearranging gives a more manageable differential equation, in fact a separable equation of first order in $x'(y)$:
$$y^2 x''(y)^2 - x'(y)^2 - 1 = 0 .$$

> Writing $u(y) := x'(y)$ reduces the equation to $y^2 u'(y)^2 - u^2 - 1 = 0$, and separating and integrating yields $$u(y) = \pm \sinh (\log y + C).$$ The tangent to the original curve through $(0, 1)$ passes through $(0, 0)$, so $u(1) = x'(1) = 0$, and substituting gives $C = 0$, so $$u(y) = \pm\sinh(\log y) = \pm\left(\frac{y}{2} - \frac{1}{2 y}\right) .$$ Since $x(y)$ is decreasing on $(0, 1)$, $u(y) = x'(y)$ is negative on that interval, hence we need the solution with $\pm = +$: $$u(y) = \frac{y}{2} - \frac{1}{2 y}.$$ Integrating again yields $$x(y) = \frac{1}{4} y^2 - \frac{1}{2} \log y + D .$$ Since our curve passes through $(0, 1)$, we find that $D = -\frac{1}{4}$, so our curve is $$x(y) = \frac{1}{4}(y^2 - 1) - \frac{1}{2} \log y .$$ Finally, the area under the curve is $$\int_0^\infty y(x) \,dx = \int_0^1 x(y) \,dy = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{1}{4}(y^2 - 1) - \frac{1}{2} \log y\right] \,dy = \boxed{\frac{1}{3}} ,$$ in agreement with your numerical computation.

**Remark** Inverting gives $y$ as a function of $x$ in terms of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$y(x) = \sqrt{-W(-e^{-4 x - 1})}.$$

Comment: Thank you! But please could I ask for a bit of clarification, how do you go from your first equation to your second equation? I don't really follow how you did that.

Comment: (I think you meant "the tangent to the curve at $(0,1)$ is $x=0$". And in the last integral, the upper limit should be $1$, not $\infty$.)

Comment: Oh never mind, I see how to get your second equation. I just took the graph in my question, flipped it across $y=x$, then wrote an equation that expresses the fact that the arc length equals the $y$-intercept of the tangent, then differentiated with respect to $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Yes, that's the geometric way to derive the equation. Alternatively (as we can for any o.d.e. in principle), we can express $x, y(x), y'(x), y''(x), \ldots$ in terms of $x, y, x'(y), x''(y), \ldots$. In our case, all we need is, $y'(x) = x'(y)^{-1}$, $y''(x) = -\frac{x''(y)}{x'(y)^3}$.